# Converting from Chi Square to Hedges in the context of mixed effects model comparisons

Tags: mixed-model, meta-analysis, effect-size

I'm attempting to extract a Hedges' G effect size from a publication that reports the chi square statistic (and degrees of freedom) derived from comparing two mixed effects models: the first model contains a binary grouping variable (treatment vs control) and the second model removed this grouping variable. I want to get an effect size for treatment vs control so I imagine if I could convert the chi-square value to Hedges' G then I would be able to include the study in my meta-analysis.

Please let me know if my thinking on this is correct and/or if this is possible.